# Configure vbs "hello world" script for EditPlus user tool

Tags: vbscript, editplus

How do I configure an EditPlus user tool (Preferences dialog box) to execute a vbs script that simply pastes a "Hello World" string to an open file?  I use editPlus version 3.30/

Answer (score 0):

EditPlus text editor: How to create a script that will paste a string.  The script can serve as a  user toolbar item to paste custom code snippets.

Configure the Preference/Tools dialog like this:

Command:

`Cscript.exe "$(AppDir)\filters\Pastetext.js"`

Argument: `//NoLogo $(CurRow)`

leave initial directory blank

Action:

```
Run as text (Insert)
```

Save Option: Select "Current file"

Save the following line as Pastetext.js in the appropriate directory

```
`WScript.echo("Hello World");`
```

The string will print where your cursor is in an open document.